# Formatting Fake usb thumb drive

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

I "bought" (for free) a 2TB usb drive and I can't make it work: tried formatting, creating mbr and gpt partition tables and always I get the same result: in some point I get a I/O error like `I/O error, dev sdc, sector 4095998192`, then I have to disconnect and reconnect. When I open the drive with gdisk or partitionmanager, the partitions are gone, and gdisk tells that the gpt is damaged.
The vid/pid of the drive is `048d:1234`, but sometimes it changes to `1e3d:198a`.
Anybody has any idea of what can I try to make it work? I don't care if I can use 2 teras, only 1 giga or 1,44mb; the idea is just to make it work

Comment: Those drives are usually 8GB in real size. However, I strongly recommend you don't use them. Not even for the 8GB of actual size. In your case however it simply seems damaged, which is unrelated to the "fake controller" case (I guess). On a working drive you could use tools like `f3` to get the real size of the drive and format it using the sectors `f3` tells you, then you end up with a sort-of-normal 8GB drive.

Comment: http://oss.digirati.com.br/f3/ - Check it out!

Comment: thanks @confetti, i'm trying to use f3probe since this morning but when I ran it, I get the i/o errors and f3 says "bad news: the device is damaged" .. I'm not gonna use it, it's more a learning thing I think

Comment: Sounds a lot like damage to the entire controller (if not more) of the drive to me, so not much you can do